# Multiplication with big number (string) function is only possible with atleast one number being 2 digits

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

So I created a function where if atleast one of the numbers is 2 digits, it would undergo the calculation properly. I want to generalize it to make both numbers be any number of digits. My code is the following:

```
string Multiply(string num1, string num2)
{
    if (num1.length() > num2.length())
    {

        string temp = num1;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = temp;
    }

    string result;
    vector<string> add;
    int carry = 0;
    int value;

    reverse(num1.rbegin(), num1.rend());
    reverse(num2.rbegin(), num2.rend());

    for (int i = 0; i < num1.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num2.length(); j++)
        {
            value = (num1[i] - '0') * (num2[j] - '0') + carry;

            char val = (char)value;

            if (value > 9)
            {
                carry = (value - value%10)/10;
                value = value % 10;
                value += '0';
                val = value;
                result += val;
            }
            else
            {
                carry = 0;
                value += '0';
                val = value;
                result += val;
            }
        }
        reverse(result.rbegin(), result.rend());
        add.push_back(result);
        result = "";
        result += string(i+1,'0');
    }
    result = Add(add[0],add[1]);
    return result;
}
```

The Add function thats included is a function I have written that adds two strings and it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just convert your `string`s to `int`s, multiply them, and convert back to a `string`?  The code would be far simpler.

Comment: @StephenNewell As the title suggests, it include big numbers so doing that wont work.

Comment: Your carry logic is crazy. `carry = value/10; value %= 10; result += value+'0';` is all that is required. No if's or but's at all.

Comment: And `value - value%10` does nothing if you are about to divide by 10 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can add the resulting value with the next value within a for loop so that it looks something like this:

```
result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < add.size(); i++)
    {
        result = Add(add[i], result);
    }
```